# MySQL is not allowing me to insert rows when I do not include a value for the auto incrementing field in the sql statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have set the CustomerID to auto-increment but when I try to insert with a statement like:
`INSERT INTO customerinfo VALUES ("Bromm@gmail.com", "De Carlo", 19)` I get a response saying

```
Error Code: 1366. Incorrect integer value: 'Bromm' for column 'CustomerID' at row 1
```

Shouldn't it need a value for the primary key anymore since it's set to auto-increment?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not naming the columns caused MySQL to inject value for Email into the first column `CustomerID`

You must specify the columns you are inserting

```
INSERT INTO customerinfo (CustomerEmail,CustomerName)
VALUES ("Bromm@gmail.com", "De Carlo");
```